# How to regex hashtag with digits after in python2?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, hashtag, digit

I want to find a hashtag with 1 to 6 digits after with python 2.7 and my regex doesn't match properly.

Here is my example :

```
chaine = "[url=http://forum.darkgyver.fr/t27142-probleme-boitier-papillon-faisceau#265132:<UID>]http://forum.darkgyver.fr/t27142-probleme-boitier-papillon-faisceau#265132[/url:<UID>]"
regex = re.compile('http://forum.darkgyver.fr/(.*)\#(\d{1-6})')
match = regex.search(chaine)
if match:
        pos1 = match.start()
        pos2 = match.end()
else:    
        pos1 = -1
        pos2 = -1

print "pos1 %d" % pos1
print "pos2 %d" % pos2
url_tempo = chaine[pos1:pos2]
print "url_tempo %s" % url_tempo            
posPost = pos1 + url_tempo.find('#') + 1
numPost = chaine[posPost:pos2]
print "numPost %s" % numPost
```

This first regex returns "no match". Perhaps the hashtag is not declared properly.

So I changed my regex as follows:

```
regex = re.compile('http://forum.darkgyver.fr/(.*)\#([0-9]+(:| |    |\n|\[|$))')
```

which matches the wrong position `pos2=161` should be `pos2=80`

How can I fix my regex to the hashtag and the 1 to 6 digits behind?

Comment: `\d{1,6}` .....................not `\d{1-6}`

Comment: Thank you Martin for this first answer. I have try

regex = re.compile('http://forum.darkgyver.fr/(.*)\#(\d{1,6})')

It match partially, pos2 should be "80" instead of "160", and numpost does not contain the good string should be only "265132"

pos2=160
numPost 265132:<UID>]http://forum.darkgyver.fr/t27142-probleme-boitier-papillon-faisceau#265132

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to extract the hashtag from the URL. From the string you have given, it would seem more logical to try and simply extract all digits between the `#` and the `:` characters. If you had a hashtag with 7 digits, would you want all 7 digits or would you want to not match it? In any case, I would guess you would not just want the first 6 digits.

By using the grouping operator `()`, if there is a match, your hashtag can be seen by just using the `qroup(1)` command, avoiding the need to try and extract it using string slicing.

The following shows you one possible way to extract the hashtag:

```
chaine = "[url=http://forum.darkgyver.fr/t27142-probleme-boitier-papillon-faisceau#265132:<UID>]http://forum.darkgyver.fr/t27142-probleme-boitier-papillon-faisceau#265132[/url:<UID>]"

re_hashtag = re.search(re.escape("http://forum.darkgyver.fr") + ".*?#(\d+):", chaine)

print re_hashtag.start()    
print re_hashtag.end()
print re_hashtag.group(1)
```

This will display the following:

```
5
80
265132
```

The start position of `5` is because it starts by matching your chosen `http`.

Note, I have used the [escape()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) function to make sure your URL is correctly escaped. If you print the following you will see how your initial regular expression should have been written:

```
print re.escape("http://forum.darkgyver.fr")
```

Giving:

```
http\:\/\/forum\.darkgyver\.fr
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Martin for your answer.

- I must escape correctly my url with escape function
- I am going to use re.search to find the digit after the hashtag directly into an array : re.search(re.escape("http://forum.darkgyver.fr") + ".*?#(\d+):", chaine)

I agree with you it's the best solution.
François